# Подбор движка wiki для внутреннего использования

Tags: php, cms

Но не могу выбрать движок по этим требованиям. Может быть кто-то уже искал себе и поможет.

1. Наличие авторизации, разделения пользователей на группы.
2. Разграничение прав доступа пользователей к различным разделам wiki.
3. Работа на платформе php/mysql.
4. Лицензия GNU GPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) не угодил?